How to separate integer from a string
I need to separate integer from a string. So I can separate "abc10" as abc in token1 and 10 in token2 using below in golang
    const regexString = "([A-Z|a-z]+)"
    var mystr = regexp.MustCompile(regexString)
    .....
    token := "abc10"
    token1 := ""
    token2 := ""
    matches := mystr.FindStringSubmatch(token)
    switch matchLen {
    case 0, 1:
        token1 = ""
        token2 = token
    case 2:
        token1 = matches[1]
        _, token2, _ = strings.Cut(token, matches[1])
    }

But facing issue, how to do the same, if input is of below form:
token: "hello abc1" --> token1: "hello abc", token2: 1
or
token: "final count3/2" --> token1: "final count", token2: "3/2"

Try iterating over the string backward to identify where the last numeric or fractional part starts:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

// SeparateToken tries to separate a string into two parts:
//   - token1 (the part before the last numeric or fractional part)
//   - token2 (the last numeric or fractional part)
func SeparateToken(token string) (string, string) {
    n := len(token)
    for i := n - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if !unicode.IsDigit(rune(token[i])) && token[i] != '/' {
            return token[:i+1], token[i+1:]
        }
    }
    // If no numeric or fractional part is found, return the entire token as token1.
    return token, ""
}

func main() {
    testCases := []string{
        "abc10",
        "hello abc1",
        "final count3/2",
        "xyz",
        "apple 32 banana 10",
    }
    for _, testCase := range testCases {
        token1, token2 := SeparateToken(testCase)
        fmt.Printf("%q -> token1: %q, token2: %q\n", testCase, token1, token2)
    }
}

Output:
"abc10" -> token1: "abc", token2: "10"
"hello abc1" -> token1: "hello abc", token2: "1"
"final count3/2" -> token1: "final count", token2: "3/2"
"xyz" -> token1: "xyz", token2: ""
"apple 32 banana 10" -> token1: "apple 32 banana ", token2: "10"

Try on Go Playground
